# Reporting to excel in yii2 something wrong

Tags: excel, yii, yii2, reporting, phpexcel

I've tried to created reporting to excel in yii2. The first, I've make file excel as to accommodate data when I click button export in view/index.php. And I put in file app/views/donatur.
The second, I've added actionExportExcel in controllers, the goal for generating data to format excel with using library PHPExcel.
Something wrong, I don't know why, error this below.

> Could not open $app/views/donatur/excel.xlsx for reading! File does not exist.

code in controller

```html
public function actionExportExcel()
    {
        $searchModel = new DonaturSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        $objReader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
        
        // set tempate
        $template = Yii::getAlias('$app/views/donatur').'/excel.xlsx';
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($template);
        $activeSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

        // Set orientasi & ukuran kertas 
        $activeSheet->getPageSetup()->setOrientation(\PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)->
        setPaperSize(\PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::PAPERSIZE_FOLIO);
        $baseRow = 4;
        foreach ($dataProvider->getModels() as $donatur) {
            $activeSheet->setCellValue('A'.$baseRow, $baseRow-2)->
            setCellValue('B'.$baseRow, $category->nama_donatur)->
            setCellValue('C'.$baseRow, $category->alamat)->
            setCellValue('D'.$baseRow, $category->telepon);
            $baseRow++;
        }
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= "excel.xlsx"');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
        $objWriter = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, "Excel2007");
        $objWriter->save('php://output');
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `@app/views/donatur` instead of `$app/views/donatur`?

Comment: I've tried which @app/views/donatur. It work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In alias you should use @ and not $

```
 $template = Yii::getAlias('@app/views/donatur').'/excel.xlsx';
```